# How to count word "test" in file on Python?

Tags: python

I have a file consists of many strings. Looks like

> sdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf test gggg uff 
>   test test fffffffff
>   sdgsdgsdgsdg sdgsdgsdgsdg uuuttt 
>   555555555 ddfdfdfff dddd4444 66677565
>   sdfsdf5 556e4ergferg ergdgdfgtest kdfgdfgfg test

How to count all words "test". I tried, but I have only this result

```
f = open("file")
words =  0
for s in f:
    i = s.find('test')
    if i > -1:
        words += 1
print(words)
f.close()
```

And this script counts only strings where contain word "test". How to count words?

Comment: This is pretty easy with a `collections.Counter` (or any `dict`) if you know how to use them and how to split strings based on whitespace...

Comment: Why not `s.count` instead?

Comment: @IronFist -- `.count` would also pick up other words like `'testing'`, `'testosterone'`, etc.

Comment: Should it count `testword`, since it contains `test`, or must it be an exact match to the word `test`?  Is there punctuation (ie. should `,test` and `test.` also match?  What about case sensitivity (ie. `TEST`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all matches:

```
with open("file") as f:
    numtest = f.read().count("test")
```

If you want to find only word matches:

```
with open("file") as f:
    numtest = f.read().split().count("test")
```

Comment: He only needs your second option

Comment: That's okay.  There might be future people who find the first option helpful.

Comment: btw - I didn't know it - does the function `count()` work on both strings and lists?

Comment: Yes it does.  I had to check myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

`s.split().count('test')`

Comment: Additional: `s.count('test')` will match `ergdgdfgtest` too.

Comment: @struct -- But not with the `.split`.  That said, you'd probably want `s.split().count('test')` to split on any whitespace, not just `' '`

Comment: I'd remove the `' ' ` from the `.split()`

Comment: Done deal. Will now split on any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
   from collections import Counter
   with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
       words = f.read().split()
       counts = Counter(words)

   print counts["test"] #counts just of exact string "test"
   #find all strings containing test (e.g 'atest', 'mytest')
   print sum([val for key,val in counts.iteritems() if "test" in key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

cnt = len(re.findall(r'\btest\b', txt))
```

If you don't care about case sensitivity (also match `Test` or `TEST`)

```
cnt = len(re.findall(r'\btest\b', txt, flags=re.I))
```

Answer (score 0):

It will count number of `test`s in the whole file:

```
f = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
num_tests = len([word for word in f.read().split() if word == 'test'])
f.close()
```

Note that it will **NOT** match words like `tester, tested, testing, etc....`
If you want to also match them, use instead:

```
f = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
num_tests = len([word for word in f.read().split() if 'test' in word])
f.close()
```